# How can i assign xml scripts in to a php variable?

Tags: php, xml

I can not assign a xml scripts in to a php variable.

**My xml text:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss version="2.0"><channel>
    <title>coolajax.net</title>
    <link>http://www.hotscripts.com/listings/feed</link>
    <description>Coolajax Scripts Listings Description</description>
```

and I want to assign this text in to **`$xml_header`** variable.

can anyone help me..

Comment: xml script...? what is that ? I suggest you gives details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I guess it was just a rude form of spam.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HEREDOC Syntax](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for this:

```
$xml_header = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rss version="2.0"><channel>
    <title>coolajax.net</title>
    <link>http://www.hotscripts.com/listings/feed</link>
    <description>Coolajax Scripts Listings Description</description>
XML;
```

Just make sure you start the XML string on the next line at the first position.